# Which is the easiest way to extract queue from pika

Tags: python, testing, rabbitmq, pika

Ok people. 
I'm bit rusty with Python so please go easy on me. 
I have a RabbitMQ server that I connect to, and I'm building a simple interface for sanity check, and I'm using pika.

My code looks very simple:

```
class RabbitMQConnector(object):
    """ Class that instantiates the connection, and the test interface for
    the RabbitMQ services.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(Config.USERNAME, Config.PASSWORD)
        log.info("Credentials are being set")
        self._parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(Config.HOST, credentials=self._credentials)
        log.info("Connection parameters are being set")
        self._connection = pika.BlockingConnection(self._parameters)
        self._channel = self._connection.channel()
        # We pass an empty string into the queue so we can get the random queue name
        self._replyQueue = self._channel.queue_declare(queue='')
        log.info("Reply queue name has been initialized %s" % self._replyQueue)
        log.info("Connection initialized")
        Config.time.sleep(5)
        log.info("[x] System is fully initialized, and ready to accept RabbitMQ connections")

    def connect(self):
        pass

    def disconnect(self):
        pass
```

But when I call this method:

```
log.info("Reply queue name has been initialized %s" % self._replyQueue)
```

My reply gets like:

```
Reply queue name has been initialized <METHOD(['channel_number=1', 'frame_type=1', "method=<Queue.DeclareOk(['consumer_count=0', 'message_count=0', 'queue=amq.gen-8GVTfmr8noMB5slpXnFRHQ'])>"])>
```

And the only thing I want to display to user is actually this queue

```
queue=amq.gen-8GVTfmr8noMB5slpXnFRHQ
```

What would be the easiest way to extract this variable from the above method?
Thank you.

p/s: `log` is just an alias for logger, whilst `Config.USERNAME` and `Config.PASSWORD` are just 'user' and 'localhost'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [3rd rabbitmq tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html), code for receiver:

```
result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
```

Quote from the aforementioned link (under title *Temporary queues*):

> ...we could create a queue with a random name, or, even better - let the
>   server choose a random queue name for us. We can do this by not
>   supplying the queue parameter to queue_declare:
>
> `result = channel.queue_declare()`
>  At this point result.method.queue
>   contains a random queue name.

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you so much @cantSleepNow